# 2 mm accuracy in an affordable water level sensor (pressure transducer) - Does one exist?

Tags: pressure, water-resources, hydrology

I'm looking to conduct water level monitoring in streams and rivers for water resource engineering purposes. My plan is to use Arduinos and Raspberry Pis in conjunction with a pressure transducer, as Pis and Arduinos work with the telemetry system and water quality sensors that I have chosen for the project.

However, the standards in British Columbia, Canada (where I work) require that the sensor must have a 2 mm accuracy to collect "Grade A" data. Grade B data requires 5 mm accuracy, and as it turns out a pressure transducer with these accuracies are hard to find unless you spend >$500 per pressure transducer.

Does anyone know if a low cost ($300 max, but preferably $50 to $150) pressure transducer designed for measuring water with 2 mm or 5 mm accuracy exist? I'm also open to other technologies as well.

Thanks!

Page 4 in the attached in BC's [standards doccument](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/assets/gov/environment/air-land-water/water/science-data/man_bc_hydrometric_stand_v10.pdf) is attached if anyone is interested in checking it out.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: Does it have to be a pressure transducer, or would some other mechanism be OK?

Comment: I've been looking at other instruments such as ultrasonics. We actually purchased a MB7369 HRXL-MaxSonar-WRM (link below), but ultrasonics come with some qualities that make them less desirable than pressure transducers when measuring a fluctuating water level such as the case with fast flowing streams.

Comment: https://maxbotix.com/Ultrasonic_Sensors/MB7369.htm

Comment: V notch or rectangular weirs may be considered - this may need a section of the river bed prepared to give a smooth flow...

Comment: I suggest you include the suggested Ultrasonic sensor in the body of the question. With regard to cost it is best you work with sales and sourcing teams.

Comment: I would vote to reopen this if it were rephrased as "what is a cost effective type of instrument for measuring water levels to 2 or 5mm accuracy?", although I admit I recognize I'm not in majority on my opinion about the on-topic-ness of these questions. I'm curious though, what does it even mean to measure a river height to 2mm? The water level certainly varies more than that across its profile!